# C++ VS 2013 Error "Unable to start program"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am constantly getting this error when debugging my code on VSE 2013 "Unable to start program 'C:.....\FILENAME.exe" "The system cannot find the file specified"

This only ever happens when I create a new header and include it in my main.cpp.
I tried navigating to the directory of my solution and i located the .exe of it. When making a simple code that prints something the .exe remains in the folder though when including my header the .exe just disappears...

Comment: have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: yes i have tried that

Comment: Sounds like the build is _failing_ so you don't have an .exe. Did you look at the compilation results? Something in your header may be breaking your program's ability to be compiled.

Comment: Any fancy parts in the path name? Something like mixing several character sets (say Chinese plus Cyrillic)? What OS? What update level for VS 2013? Does the path link (symlink or junction point) to anything? Is the path on OneDrive/SkyDrive or similar?

Comment: I'm quite sure the header is not the problem as there is just one project that this header works completely fine in whereas in any other new projects i create it just doesnt work for some reason

Comment: Hmm ok so i just found out that there is one project that when i run works fine though when i copy and paste the exact same code into a new project is get this error...

Comment: and the path name has nothing out of the ordinary just normal letters and it isn't on a cloud drive